# Showing the values in dart Visual Code in hex in the watch windows

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Sometimes it is helpful to show the variables in the watch window in hex. We have this feature in Visual Studio. Here we can say "Hexadecimal Display". 
Is there a workaround for that to do the same in dart and Visual Code?

I know about printing the values in hex over a function but this is not for what I am locking.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in mechanism for this in VS Code of the Dart extension, but you can add `.toRadisString(16)` to the expression in the Watch window:

[image]